# In jqgrid, rowobject value is undefined in first page and rowObject values are returned in next pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid-4.8 I am getting `rowObject` value as undefined in first page and receiving values in next pages if I used `rowObject.name`. if I used `rowObject[0]` then `rowObject` values as getting from cells in first page but not in subsequent pages. plz help to solve this issue.

```
 {name:'snp',index:'snp', width:100, align:"center"},
 {name:'chr',index:'chr', width:100, align:"center"},
 {name:'pos',index:'pos', width:100, align:"center"},
 {name:'calls',index:'calls',width:120,align:"center",sortable:false,formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){ return '<a href="http://localhost/var/sub1.php?id='+rowObject.snp+'&chr='+rowObject.chr+'&pos='+rowObject.pos+'" target="_blank"><font color="0000FF">view</a>';} }
```

If I use `rowObject[0]` & `rowObject[1]` is also not fully functional, it is functional in first page, not is next pages. it is showing cell values as undefined

Comment: It will be helpful if you prepare a example demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem, which you described is old known. Old version of jqGrid makes difficult to write custom formatter where you have to access data from another column if you use array of items as input data. Simple trick described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6668003/315935) allows to write the corresponding code. Instead of `$.isArray` one should better use `Array.isArray` method.

If you use free jqGrid then you can solve the problem more easier. I don't changed the format of the 3-d parameter (`rowObject`) of custom formatter, but I added `rowData` property to `options` option with *named* data. Thus you can use the following code in free jqGrid:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
    var item = options.rowData;
    return '<a href="http://localhost/var/sub1.php?id=' + 
        item.snp + '&chr=' + item.chr + '&pos=' + item.pos +
        '" target="_blank"><font color="0000FF">view</a>';
}
```

Additionally I would strictly recommend you to use **current** version of free jqGrid (4.15.4 or probably 4.15.5) instead of retro version 4.8, which is not more supported.